# Getting subprocess.Popen stdout when running by cron

Tags: python, linux, cron, popen

I want to get a service status and if it's not up, to send the status (stdout) in email.
This script is scheduled to run every hour by cron.
When running manually, the following works fine:

```
def is_service_running(name):
    with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as hide_output:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['service', name, 'status'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        output = proc.stdout.read()
        exit_code = proc.wait()
        return exit_code == 0, output
```

But when running by cron. `output` is empty.
How can I capture `stdout` when running by cron?
Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you use `result = subprocess.run(['service', name, 'status'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` and then `output = result.stdout`?

Comment: In this case the script fails to run by cron and produce `file not found` error. the `shell=True` must stay

Comment: You replied to the wrong comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't cron but `shell=True`.
Apparently, when using `shell=True`, popen expects single string and not a list.
So when I updated my call to:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['service ' + name + ' status'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

everything worked.

Comment: Actually, removing `shell=True` would be a much better fix.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: @tripleee if I set shell to false, I get the following error when running by cron: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: It's not clear what causes that, try `e = os.environ.copy(); e.update({'PATH': os.environ['PATH'] + ':/usr/sbin'); proc = subprocess.Popen(..., env=e)` but this is pure speculation. Fixing the error is still a better solution than calling a shell.